# What's wrong with using API keys to authenticate end users with API Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a small webapp that calls several Lambda functions. I need to authenticate users based on a simple passphrase. No need for specific users etc.

I am thinking of implementing this using a Lambda that takes the passphrase, matches it and returns an API key which is accepted by the rest of the Lambdas. API keys are meant to be used for developers so I know this isn't the intended use.

Is there anything insecure about doing this? The only issue I can see is that if the API key gets compromised then it's permanent, e.g
it doesn't expire after 1 hour like a token. But in that case I just generate new keys.

Otherwise it seems secure to me. Am I wrong?

Comment: "API keys are meant to be used for developers so I know this isn't the intended use." - please elaborate.

Comment: Instead of API keys, why not use signed requests?

Comment: @Dai User authentication is meant to be done via Cognito or the implementation of some OAuth flow. The docs state that API keys are for giving developers programmatic access to your API. Regarding signed requests, it looks like that's only for when you are running the AWS-SDK in a private environment. Since this is a public website that wouldn't work.

Comment: That depends on how your authx system works. Using signed requests has nothing to do with AWS - it's just another alternative authx scheme you could implement yourself.

Comment: @Dai Apologies, I've never implemented auth before. I am just amazed that people are still implementing their own solutions - auth has been done millions of times before, I expected to see one or two main NPM packages that did it for you. It seems people are reinventing the wheel each time unless they go down the complicated OAuth route. I think implementing a simple bearer auth token system might suit my use case best - that way the tokens invalidate themselves after a set period of time.

Comment: "auth has been done millions of times before" - yes, but auth is also very domain-specific. "I expected to see one or two main NPM packages that did it for you" - not everyone uses JavaScript for server-side development, in fact I'd wager it's still a minority.

Comment: @Dai I am not wedded to using Javascript on the server; I'll use anything. My only requirement is that it fits into a static website setup - that could be a serverless .NET, Java, PHP etc. backend.

Comment: Define "static website setup". Using ASP.NET or PHP means it won't be "static".